# Complex proof problem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let be **P(z)** a complex polynomial with a degree of **n>=1** and **|(p(z)| <= a|z|** then there exist a complex number **c** such that **p(z) = cz**.

Comment: If you look at $z$ with a very small absolute value, you can conclude that $p$ cannot have a constant term, because the RHS of your inequality gets arbitrarily small, so the LHS must also. If you look at $z$ with a large absolute value, you can conclude that the degree of $p$ cannot be larger than one, because otherwise the LHS of your inequality will grow faster than $z$. That leaves $p(z)=cz$ as the only possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(z) = p(z)/z$.  This is holomorphic everywhere except possibly at $0$.  We also have $|f(z)|\leq a$ everywhere but $0$.  Can you see why $f$ must be holomorphically extendable to $0$? (Hint: there is a theorem about such singularities). Now $f$ is a bounded entire function...

Comment: Yes I recall a theorem about removable singularity

Comment: Thanks Steven Gubkin I Understand it perfectly (By using Liouville's Theorem). Thank you :)